# How to deal with async function results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

Coming from a c# background, I'm probably looking at JavaScript from a completely wrong perspective, so please bear with me.

Leaving the advantages of async aside for a minute,
let's say I simply want to retreive a value from an SQLite database in an HTML5 page.
What I want to see is something like

```
var something = db.getPicture(1);
```

Now consider a (perhaps very naive) implementation of this:

```
this.getPicture(id)
{
    this.database.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT ......', null, function(tx, results)
        {
            if (results.rows.length == 1)
                return results.rows.items(0).Url; //This of course does not resturn
                                                    //anything to the caller of .getPicture(id)
        }
    },
    function(error)
    {
        //do some error handling
    },
    function(tx)
    {
        //no error
    });                     
}
```

First off, it's one big mess of nested functions and second... there's no way for me to return the result I got from the database as the value of the .getPicture() function.

And this is the easy version, what if I wanted to retreive an index from a table first,
then use that index in the next query and so on...

Is this normal for JavaScript developers, am I doing it completely wrong, is there a solution, etc...

Comment: Yes, you're doing it completely wrong :-)  To deal with the asynchronous nature of things, you pass *callback* functions around. Those are invoked by the runtime system when the time comes for it to do so, so returning values from a callback does not make any sense.

Comment: To get getPicture to return something would require you to block execution of getPicture until the async stuff has completed, and use the async callback to populate a return variable.

Comment: @Pointy: consider upgrading your comment to an answer

Comment: @KeesdeKooter really this is an extremely frequent question; I've been looking for a good duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic pattern to follow in JavaScript (in asynchronous environments like a web browser or Node.js) is that the work you need to do when an operation is finished should happen in the "success" callback that the API provides. In your case, that'd be the function passed in to your "executeSql()" method.

```
this.getPicture = function(id, whenFinished)
{
    this.database.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT ......', null, function(tx, results)
        {
            if (results.rows.length == 1)
                whenFinished(results.rows.items(0).Url);
        }
    },
```

In that setup, the result of the database operation is passed as a parameter to the function provided when "getPicture()" was invoked.

Because JavaScript functions form *closures*, they have access to the local variables in the calling context.  That is, the function you pass in to "getPicture()" as the "whenFinished" parameters will have access to the local variables that were live at the point "getPicture()" is called.